# Job DSL: Pipeline : unable to resolve class error while executing jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, dsl, jenkins-job-dsl

I have created one dsl pipeline job as below: JenklinsFile.groovy

```
pipelineJob("mbd1") {
      definition {
        cpsScm {
          scm {
            git {
              remote {
                url("<url>")
                credentials("212-12ljjl-211212-121212")
              }
              branch('master')
            }
          }
          scriptPath("src/main/groovy/company/jobs/stage/JenklinsFile.groovy")
            
        }
      }
    }
```

and my git repo is in structure below:

```
src
|- main 
     |-src/main/groovy/company
                        |- /jobs.stage/
                                 |- JenklinsFile.groovy
                                 |- XYZ.groovy 
                         | common - HttpResponse.groovy
                         | util - HttpRequestProcessorUtil.groovy
```

where HttpRequestProcessorUtil.groovy is helper class containing some utilities. similarly i have other classes.
My JenklinsFile.groovy is below

```
package main.groovy.company.jobs.stage

import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import main.groovy.company.common.HttpResponse
import main.groovy.company.util.HttpRequestProcessorUtil

def gitAccessToken
def controlSessionId
def pullRequestId
def deployId
def deployStatus



pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage('Setting Credentials') {
      steps {
        script {
          withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '<id>', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USER', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PWD')]) {
            gitAccessToken = GIT_PWD
          }
        }
      }
    }
    .
    .
    .
    .
  }
}
```

while executing the JenklinsFile.groovy i am getting below issue:

```
WorkflowScript: 5: unable to resolve class main.groovy.company.util.HttpRequestProcessorUtil
 @ line 5, column 1.
   import main.groovy.company.util.HttpRequestProcessorUtil
   ^

WorkflowScript: 4: unable to resolve class main.groovy.company.common.HttpResponse
 @ line 4, column 1.
   import main.groovy.company.common.HttpResponse
   ^
```

when I checked the workspagce of this job, its not cloning the git repo too.
What step I am missing.

Comment: did you uncheck lightweight checkout? Also I think you need to change the script path to "$workspace/src/main/groovy/company/jobs/stage/JenklinsFile.groovy" (or $workspace@script) but that is just a guess

Comment: The Declarative pipeline performs a SCM checkout on every agent by default. Hope you don't have skipDefaultCheckout set to true anywhere in the pipeline script.

Comment: @smelm  no , its not working

Comment: @PankajSaini its not working